# WinHttpRequest isn't grabbing whole page in VB6

Tags: windows, programming, microsoft

This code only captures the first part of the page, I think because the whole page doesn't load until you scroll to the bottom of the page, which I don't know how to do programatically.

```
Set http = New WinHttpRequest
x = "https://www.flickr.com/photos/conationalguard/page1"
http.Open "GET", x, "False"
http.Send
myval = http.ResponseText
```